# How to make a multi line title on a radio button using UIView

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode9.3

How to make this a multiline?

radio button title:
[image: the radio button title]

identity inspector:
[image: the identity inspector]

Comment: ios or macos or tvos?

Answer (score 1):

**Install DLRadioButton:**

```
pod 'DLRadioButton'
```

• **Add UIButton to UIView**

• **In the attributes inspector, change your button's type to custom**

• **In the identity inspector, change your button's custom class to DLRadioButton**

• **In the attributes inspector, change your text to whatever you like. Do this programatically if you like**

• **Then in the attributes inspector, change your Button's "Line Break" attribute to "Character Wrap"**

[DLRadioButton Source](https://github.com/DavydLiu/DLRadioButton)

Answer (score 0):

This is a screenshot to add on to Phillip Jacobs' answer.

1. Make sure you are using DLRadioButton class.
2. Change Line Break to "Character Wrap" or "Word Wrap" as shown in screenshot.

[image: Line Break Character Wrap location]